# Yocto. How to mix old and new override syntax

Tags: embedded, yocto, yocto-recipe

We have Yocto recipe which we deliver to our customer. Customers use different versions of yocto and Linux Kernel.

Is it possible to deliver one recipe for the old and new syntax?
Or we should always deliver 2 version of recipes?

Comment: use different branches?

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk Different branches is the same as different meta layers.

Comment: No, it's not. This is literally how The Yocto project functions - you're supposed to have different branches for your meta-layer for each release.